# Can I pass 'parameter' from Interface Builder  so my ViewController class know how to handle differently?

Tags: iphone, ios, nib

In my project I have a view (defined in a xib) that is a reusable component and will be places in many other views, I have my view controller class designed to handle different modes for this view.

My apps have 3 tabs basically use this same view, by initialize with different parameters they work pretty nice. I load this view from the Interface Builder (by specify the NIB name and class name), but I will have to pass different parameters so my view controller will know which mode it is.

I am wondering can I define some 'parameter' from Interface Builder, so my view controller class can simply look up and determinate itself. So I don't need to write any additional code to reuse this nib in many different places?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up use the "title" to pass a json string and it works for me pretty well, I am not sure if there is a better way to do so.

Answer (score 1):

Your other option then would be to use the tag parameter on the view controller's view - if you're not already using it for something else.

Your viewController would then read it's main view's tag and change it's behaviour accordingly.

```
myViewControllersView.tag = i;
```

Comment: Thanks! I need to pass some more complex value not just than a number.  I end up using "title" to pass those parameter.

Answer (score 0):

I'd look into creating your own custom init methods in your view controllers and use these to initialise your view controllers.

```
myViewController = [[[myUIViewController alloc] init] initWithParamOne:paramOne andParamTwo:paramTwo];

- (id) initWithParamOne:(NSString *)paramOne andParamTwo:(NSString *)paramTwo {
    self = [super initWithNibName:@"myNib" bundle:nil]; 
    if (self) {
        // code here
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason why I don't like this is, I need those additional code only set one parameter to pass to my viewcontroller. If I can pass them from Interfacebuilder I will don't need to write a single line of code, it will make the project simpler and easy to maintain since my view controller has already be able to take care all different scenarios.  Another option I didn't consider is create a bunch of inherited class from my view controller and set in IB...